# Which avionics suite does the 757 use?

Tags: avionics, boeing, boeing-757

I am wondering who makes the 757 avionics? Is there a glass cockpit upgrade? What is the name of the avionics suite?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You know, at the time the 757 was considered to be a "glass cockpit" but [yes, there is a more modern upgrade](http://www.aviationtoday.com/2017/05/09/ups-upgrade-boeing-757-767-cockpits/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original 757 cockpit was considered “glass.” It consisted of six screens: Pilot’s PFD and ND, Co-pilots PFD and ND, and an upper and lower EICAS screen.

Behind the scenes, there is a triple autopilot system (left, center and right), two flight management computers, three flight control computers, three display control units (think SGU or symbol generator), two to three air data computers depending on customer option, and two EICAS (Engine Indicating and Caution and Advisory System) computers. There are also a large number of card files that process various system discretes to provide aural warnings.

A more modern upgrade to this, called “IS&S” keeps the same “boxes” in the shelves, but changes the PFD/ND displays to 4 LCD displays. This also got rid of the standalone airspeed indicators and altimeters (save the standby) as well as VSI’s. It makes the aircraft “NextGen” compliant.